# image-url() в compass добавляет префикс

Tags: css, sass, compass

в sass прописываю путь так: `background: image-url("back.png");`
на выходе получается такой адрес изображения: `url('/img/back.png?1491902987')` и само изображение не выводится

Answer (score 0):

1 - уберите слово `image` из свойства:

```
background: url("back.png")
```

2 - проверьте адрес изображения относительно компилируемого файла `style.css` на выходе.

---

Если добавите архитектуру проекта - то возможна конкретная подсказка, а так можно сказать подсказка вслепую.

Comment: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/ вот что пытаюсь юзать

Comment: если вы используете - 'image-url($path, $only-path, $cache-buster)', то все равно хотелось бы увидеть хотя бы ахитектуру, более полный кусок кода, а так можно только гадать

Comment: Compass Config файл тоже хотелось бы увидеть в таком случае

Answer (score 0):

А зачем `image-URL`? Можно и без `image`.  И лучше это ставить в атрибут `style` у нужного тэга - там меньше парки будет.